What's wrong? I'm having problems with Solana imports @solana/spl-token
This is my package.json file:
{
  "name": "TokenCreator",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine": "6.0.1",
    "@bonfida/spl-name-service": "^2.4.2",
    "@metaplex-foundation/js": "0.20.1",
    "@metaplex-foundation/js-next": "0.11.1",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi": "0.9.1",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults": "0.9.1",
    "@metaplex/js": "4.12.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/x-charts": "^7.0.0",
    "@noble/ed25519": "^1.7.1",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.102.6",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.16.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "2.2.3",
    "@onsol/tldparser": "^0.6.4",
    "@solana/spl-token": "0.4.6",
    "@solana/spl-token-registry": "^0.2.4574",
    "@solana/spl-token-metadata": "0.1.4",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "0.9.23",
    "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.26.0",
    "@solana/buffer-layout": "^4.0.1",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "0.15.35",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "0.9.35",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "0.19.32",
    "@solana/web3.js": "1.91.7",
    "@splinetool/react-spline": "^2.2.6",
    "@splinetool/runtime": "^1.0.87",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.12",
    "@typeform/embed-react": "^3.16.0",
    "@web3-storage/w3up-client": "^13.0.0",
    "@ucanto/core": "10.0.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.48.0",
    "daisyui": "^1.24.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "firebase": "^10.11.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^13.7.3",
    "flowbite": "^2.3.0",
    "formidable": "^3.5.1",
    "framer-motion": "^11.0.24",
    "immer": "^9.0.12",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/lodash.orderby": "^4.6.9",
    "next": "^14.1.4",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^10.0.0",
    "react": "^18.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "react-redux": "9.1.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "three": "^0.163.0",
    "web3.storage": "^4.5.5",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "9.1.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}


I'm having these errors:

Module '"@solana/spl-token"' has no exported member 'PROGRAM_ID'.ts(2305)
import PROGRAM_ID
Module '"@solana/spl-token"' has no exported member 'MINT_SIZE'.ts(2305)
import MINT_SIZE
Module '"@solana/spl-token"' has no exported member 'CreateMetadataAccountV3'.ts(2305)
import CreateMetadataAccountV3
Module '"@solana/spl-token"' has no exported member 'createInitializeMintInstruction'.ts(2305)
import createInitializeMintInstruction
Module '"@solana/spl-token"' has no exported member 'getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint'.ts(2305)
import getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint

import { Token, PROGRAM_ID, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, MintLayout } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { MINT_SIZE, CreateMetadataAccountV3, createInitializeMintInstruction, getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint } from "@solana/spl-token";

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone knows what the problem is?

There are a few issues here to disentangle, mainly because you're importing things that don't exist in the @solana/spl-token package:

Token only exists in versions before 0.2
CreateMetadataAccountV3 exists in a metaplex library https://mpl-token-metadata-js-docs.vercel.app/functions/createMetadataAccountV3.html
PROGRAM_ID doesn't exist, so you'll need to use TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID or TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID

As for the other errors, I wonder if those errors came from an older version of spl-token, since everything else works as expected. Maybe you can start with an example and modify it as needed.
https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#what-do-i-need-to-get-started-with-spl-tokens has a lot of great examples
